# How to efficiently search all draft posts on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I have a large number of draft posts on Tumblr. I often want to find one draft post to continue editing the post. If I go to the drafts page, by default only the first few posts are listed. I have to press the end key multiple times in the browser in order to expose the full list of draft posts, and then I can use the browser search feature. I'd like to have a way of bringing up the full page of draft posts or some other more efficient way of searching for draft posts.

**What is an efficient way of searching for draft posts on Tumblr?**

Comment: Tumblr currently doesn't have any functionality for searching draft posts. You might be able to get an overview of all your drafts with the New XKit extension and "Drafts+", but it doesn't look like Drafts+ supports searching.